# Call a JS function in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel

Got a bit of predicament guys. I have Vue application that allows users to create schedules to take payments. For example, schedules can be ran weekly, bi-weekly, fortnightly or monthly.

Payments can be taken on specific dates such as; the 21st, 22nd, 23rd, etc, or variable dates such as; last working day of the month, first working day of the month, etc.

If it's weekly than payments will be taken on; Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.

All of this logic is quite complex and is done in JS using MomentJS in a function called createSchedule. The key variable returned by this function is the variable; executionPlan that contains all future payment dates.

The initial plan did not require an API that would allow you to create schedules from something like Postman but now this is needed. I would prefer not to re-write this code in PHP as it will be quite time consuming making the switch from Moment to something like Carbon.

Is there anyway in Laravel I can call this JS function to retrieve the execution plan?

It theoretically should look something like this, but I don't know how to call a function from  JS file:

```
$execPlan = createSchedule(startDate, endDate, frequency, collectionDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you want to call it from php though, something you could do is just run createSchedule() on your front end and then pass the data that contains all future payment dates from js to your controller using axios or whatever you're using to do http requests, or in other words, run the function on your front end before the request and send the data to the controller, but if your question is, can you call a js function from php, the answer is no you can't unless theres an api involved

Comment: This feature may be used by many sites which means I will have to keep providing the createSchedule() JS function to each site for it to work. I don't like the reliance of the API hanging on that function. Would creating a JS API using NodeJS solve this issue?